# Unable to conversion in Expected<unique_ptr<Module>> to Module

Tags: c++, c++11, llvm, llvm-ir

I am new to llvm , writing the program "main.cpp" of https://github.com/davidar/lljvm/blob/master/backend/main.cpp.

I stuck at the error while executing the command : "pm.run(m)"

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘llvm::legacy::PassManager::run(llvm::Expected<std::unique_ptr<llvm::Module> >&)
```

Here is my source code:

```
#include "backened.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "llvm/Bitcode/BitcodeReader.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/Support/CommandLine.h"
#include "llvm/Support/ErrorOr.h"
#include "llvm/Support/MemoryBuffer.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/IR/PassManager.h"
#include "llvm/CodeGen/Passes.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DataLayout.h"
#include <llvm/Transforms/Scalar.h>
#include "llvm/IR/LegacyPassManager.h"

using namespace llvm;
using namespace std;

static cl::opt<string> input(cl::Positional, cl::desc("Bitcode File.."),cl::Required);
static cl::opt<string> classname("classname",cl::desc("Binary name of the generated class..."));

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        cl::ParseCommandLineOptions(argc, argv, "Hi..");
        LLVMContext context;

        ErrorOr<unique_ptr<MemoryBuffer>>  mb = MemoryBuffer::getFile(input);
        if(error_code ec = mb.getError()) {
                errs() << ec.message();
                return 1;
        }    
        Expected<unique_ptr<Module>> m = parseBitcodeFile(mb->get()->getMemBufferRef(),context);
        if(error_code ec= errorToErrorCode(m.takeError()) )
        {
           errs() <<"Unable to read bitcode file.." <<ec.message() ;
        }
        PassManager<Module> pm; 

    pm.add(createVerifierPass());    
    pm.add(createGCLoweringPass());    
    pm.add(createLowerSwitchPass());
    pm.add(createCFGSimplificationPass());
    pm.add(new JVMWriter(fouts(), classname, debugLevel));    
    pm.add(createGCInfoDeleter());    
    pm.run(*m);    
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: How confident are you that the code is *expected* to build? The code hasn't been touched for years - the only update is the addition of a note to the readme (just a few hours ago) saying that the project is unmaintained and suggesting alternatives.

Comment: @molbdnilo, I am just taking refernce of that project,could you help me to resolve that error.

Comment: I think you should start with investigating the author's suggested alternatives.

Comment: @molbdnilo, I do not found any such author suggested alternative.

Comment: Read the end of the first paragraph of the readme.

Comment: @molbdnilo, I read it , I know flowchart is first convert llvm ir to jasmin then back to java bytecode. But I do not know how to initiate it ? So, thought better to follow his work and remove the compilation error to meet latest llvm versio 6.0.1. Please suggest me , am I doing correct?

Comment: Do you have a local version that you're looking at, which you haven't pulled for the last four hours or so? Update it, or read [this version](https://github.com/davidar/lljvm). The paragraph reads "This project is currently unmaintained. You may be interested in:..."

Comment: @molbdnilo, Yes, they have given alternative way of this project i.e. LLJVM translator which is maropu project, but problem is it is totally written in Java. I am looking for project in c++